# How to use port.emit() in a contentScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to bind a

```
self.port.emit()
```

to an event in the window, to signal my pagemod (and page-worker) to do something. However, none of my attempts at using the port.emit() function have worked.

index.js:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url("jquery.js"),
    data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
    data.url("definitionsender.js"),
    data.url("define.js")
  ],
  onAttach: function(worker){
      contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("jquery.js"),
        data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
        data.url("define.js")
      ]
      worker.port.on("updatedWord", function(){
          console.log("success");
      });
    }
});
```

define.js:

```
$(window).dblclick(function() {
    var selected = getSelected();
    if (selected!="") {
    var completedURL = "http://www.dictionary.com/browse/" + selected;
    $('#define').dialog("open");
    dictionaryRef.contentURL = completedURL;
    self.port.emit("updatedWord");
    }
});
```

[EDIT]: I went back through my code and those 3 lines did not actually change anything. However, adding a

```
var myScript = "window.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {" +
           "  var selection = window.getSelection().toString();" +
           "  if (selection != ''){" +
           "    self.port.emit('getWord', selection);" +
"}});"
```

as a contentScript to the pageMod created a working port.emit(), however, the follow-up port.emit() and port.on()s do not work.

Comment: The messaging code works fine. Are you sure that the `getSelected`  returns actually something and not returing an empty string?

Comment: @ChristosPapoulas, yes I'm positive that `getSelected` works. It returns a word that is highlighted

Comment: I ran your code and works just fine. The only thing that I dont understad is why you define again the `contentScriptFile` inside the worker callback inside `attachTo`

Comment: When I run it, I can't find the output "success" anywhere... I duplicated the contentScriptFile just as a failsafe in case it wasn't attached before, so I knew it wasn't a problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url("jquery.js"),
    data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
    data.url("definitionsender.js"),
    data.url("define.js")
  ],
  onAttach: function(worker){
      contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("jquery.js"),
        data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
        data.url("define.js")
      ]

      worker.port.on('dblclick', function(html) {
          console.log("success");
      });
    }
});
```

---

or you should use  :

index.js:

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentScriptFile: [
    data.url("jquery.js"),
    data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
    data.url("definitionsender.js"),
    data.url("define.js")
  ],
  onAttach: function(worker){
      contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("jquery.js"),
        data.url("jquery-ui.min.js"),
        data.url("define.js")
      ]
      worker.port.on("updatedWord", function(){
          console.log("success");
      });
    }
});
```

define.js:

```
$(window).dblclick(function() {
    var selected = getSelected();
    if (selected!="") {
        pageMod.port.emit("updatedWord");
    }
});
```